# Can I customize the MongoDB Connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm trying to use MongoDB connector https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/3ce6cbda-c62b-41e0-9706-f75da51e50ee and found some missing options, is it possible to customize it? where is the source code of the connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, you can fork the code and do the changes you require, and use it. The source code is located [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-mongodb). You can also consider contributing it back to WSO2.

If you want to build your own connector from scratch you can take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/customizations/creating-new-connector/).